# When I try to run this program I get an error that halts the program and says, "Vector subscript out of range"

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;


vector<int> niz(10);

int main() {

    int i;
    for(i=0; i<10; i++){
        cout<<"Unesi broj: ";
        cin>>niz[i];
    }

    vector<int> obrnuto(10);
    niz[i] = obrnuto[i];

    for(i=10; i>0; i--){
        cout<<obrnuto[i]<<",";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

it was supposed to write out numbers in the first vector backwards an save them in the second vector...what is wrong i dont know, please help

Comment: Wow, bit of a list here: 1. Use the correct tags. You tagged your question `android` and `java`, when it's clearly `C++`. 2. When you were typing your question, there was a bit orange box next to the text edit field titled **How to Format**. Worth a read. 3. Please don't include things like "4 down vote favorite" at the beginning of the title. Only include relevant information in the title. Satellite and rocketboy have fixed things for you this time.

Comment: Remember that in languages based on C (like C++ *and* Java) array indexes goes from zero to size-1.

Comment: #include <iostream> == Java???

Answer (score 4):

```
int i;
for(i=0;i<10;i++){
    cout<<"Unesi broj: ";
    cin>>niz[i];
}

vector<int> obrnuto(10);
niz[i]=obrnuto[i];
```

At this point `i == 10`, which means that by `niz[i]`, you are accessing the 11th element, one that does not exist. Same issue with `obrnuto[i]`

Remember that array indicies in most languages start from 0. i.e `int arr[10]` has elements from `arr[0]` - `arr[9]`.

From your description I think you want simply

```
niz = obrnuto;
```

Although I am not sure why you need the 2nd `vector` at all.

Also, you want

```
for(i=10; i>0; i--){
```

to be

```
for(i=9; i>=0; i--){
```

Answer (score 0):

There two major errors in your code. Both related to indexes in languages like C++.

You have to remember that in C++, the indexes of an array start as `0` to `sizeOfArray-1`.

That is  :

```
for(i=0;i<10;i++){
    cout<<"Unesi broj: ";
    cin>>niz[i];
}

vector<int> obrnuto(10);
niz[i]=obrnuto[i];          // First error

for(i=10;i>0;i--){          // Second error
    cout<<obrnuto[i]<<",";
}
```

First error : You are after your for-loop, `i=10`. So you have your first [out-of-bound](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stdexcept/out_of_range/) error here.

Second error : You start your second for-loop at 10, that is, when you do `obrnuto[i]` you are out-of-bound again.

In your case, your vectors have 10 elements, so their indexes go from `0` to `9`.

---

You can fix it by doing :

```
for(i=0;i<10;i++){
    cout<<"Unesi broj: ";
    cin>>niz[i];
}

vector<int> obrnuto(10);
niz = obrnuto; // You just want to copy the members of the vector into the second one right ?
//^^^^^^^^^^^

for ( i = 9; i >= 0; i-- ) {
    //    ^     ^
    cout<<obrnuto[i]<<",";
}
```